# how to start learning JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am experienced in the technical support like Linux, oracle, sunos etc and but if i say scripting i know little bit of bash. Now i promoted to manage technical engineers including some JavaScript developers, so i want to learn JavaScripting so that i can understand engineers. Hope you understand. Can you please advise me how can i start JavaScripting and point me to some simple docs and examples.

Comment: dear java & javascript are two totaly different things.

Comment: mmm....java script - http://hsirkel.net/dilbert/dilbert20071115.gif

Comment: You may want to check out this thread posted a few weeks ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687566/learning-javascript-in-one-weekend

Comment: JavaScript lost its importance for a decade because the name implied it was somehow inferior to Java. Netscape shouldn't have given up so easily. Not too mention the confusion it causes for newcomers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [A Beginner's Guide to JavaScript](http://www.javascriptguide.com/), it includes tips and examples and [Javascript Tutorials for Beginner's](http://homepage.ntlworld.com/kayseycarvey/)

Comment: Dead links. Please update.

Answer (score 3):

I find this the *best* free guide to javascript:
http://eloquentjavascript.net/

Answer (score 2):

[JavaScript: The Good Parts](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596517748) is a good, and thin, book. The [videos by the same author](http://video.yahoo.com/search/?p=The+JavaScript+Programming+Language) are also very good. The [MDC documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript) is excellent (but watch out for features added post-1.5 which are usually not supported by Internet Explorer).

Comment: I'm not sure I'd recommend diving straight into *JavaScript: The Good Parts* to a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

Start learning form here :

http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_intro.asp

But i think also better to start with the jquery a good library for the javascript After you done with javascript  : http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page

Comment: Out of date and packed with bad examples and IEisms.

Comment: but i think its very good for the starters

Comment: It has been shocking to find that _many_ of the things I saw on that site are frowned upon by professionals.

Comment: It isn't very good for "the starters". It gets them into bad habits really quickly.

Comment: And starting with jQuery is a deadful idea. The number of questions on this site from people who have written jQuery code that doesn't work because they don't understand how scope works in JS is shocking. Learn the language before you start with complicated DOM manipulation libraries.

Comment: thanks for the info ans is updated now

Answer (score 0):

I think **[Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/)** is a great source and particularly **[JavaScript Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide)** would be very helpful for someone to start.

Personaly, I started with [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/) and I liked the small, "digestable", easy-to-understand examples but I have changed my mind since I landed to this page: [www.w3fools.com](http://www.w3fools.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm learning javascript myself now. I think http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp is a good reference when you wanna have quick look on syntax. I always prefer to read some good books because It gives me the based knowledge about the language. Maybe I am wrong about this but i think everybody has different approach in learning.

I would recommend you to read this book:

**Professional JavaScript for Web Developers, 3rd Edition**

Which you can find the code resources here:
http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/Section/Code-Resources.id-380581.html

The code is free for download. The book is friendly to beginner.

Then you might wanna move on to:

**Object-Oriented JavaScript**

There are also good screencasts out there such as Douglas Crockford's lectures.

I hope this help. Enjoy learning :)