# How do I run a javascript code

Tags: javascript

I have been given a code to run to analyse and I cannot find where to run it, I have tried google chrome but it is confusing the hell out of me and my friend told me note plus plus but im not sure how to open that or if that even works thank you for your help

Comment: I suppose what you are asking is not how to run it, but how to learn it. Notepad++ is an editor you may use to write your code, then you can view and debug it in approximately any browser. Have a look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2926906/how-to-start-learning-javascript

Answer (score 1):

You can run it in the chrome dev tools console, or use something like https://repl.it/languages/javascript or https://jsfiddle.net/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ctrl+Maj+J to directly go to the javascript console where you can paste that code.

You can also run it by using [NodeJs](https://nodejs.org/en/)

However, you really should avoid running random code unless you know what it's doing.

Answer (score 0):

On chrome press F12 then open the tab console and here you can test your code

Answer (score 0):

I suppose what you are asking is not how to run it, but how to learn it. Notepad++ is an editor you may use to write your code, then you can view and debug it in approximately any browser. Have a look on [how to start learning JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2926906/how-to-start-learning-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options to run a js code: Nodejs and any browser you want(I suggest google-chrome)
Option 1(Nodejs): 
First you must install nodejs. There are tons of tutorials on the net. Then open cmd/terminal and navigate to the javascript file. Then type `node filename.js`.
Option 2(browser):
first create an `index.html` file in the directory where the .js file is located. Then open it with any text editor(I suggest `brackets`) and enter the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head></head>
        <body>
            <script src="filename.js"></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Now save the file and close the editor. Click with the right button on the html file and the choose open with->google-chrome. If the js file have console.logs the press `f12` while  in the browser.